# Nestjs: AuthGuard validation per request?

Tags: authentication, nestjs

I have a nestjs graphql backend and I’d like to do the token authentication **once per http request**.

The Problem:

For one http request my global defined guard `app.useGlobalGuards(new GqlAuthGuard())` is validating the user **7 times** if I have the following graphql query:

```
  {
    article(id:1)
    {
      id
      name   
    }
    categories {
      id
      name
    }
    topics {
      id
      name              
    }
    lawmakers {
      id
      name
    }
    articleTypes {
      id
      name
    }
    articleStatuses {
      id
      name
    }
    countries {
      id
      name
    }
  }
```

It looks that the AuthGuard is called for each Module that is affected by the query.

How can I get rid of this multiple validation?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably end up attaching some sort of `validated` or `authenticated` property to the request context so that on each new guard the request goes through it could be shorted with that field. The problem is that with your query, you are *essentially* making 7 http calls in one, and Nest will run the guard against each query and mutation being requested because that's how a global guard is bound. The only real way around it is just to add some sort of short circuit that makes the complex logic not happen.